# get file if jpg or jpeg in explode

Tags: php, explode

how can I save file only if it's jpg or jpeg files?

```
if($type!='0' and $type!='e'){
    $folder='extra/'.$folder;
}   
$ext=explode('.', $url);
$last=count($ext)-1;
$nomeFile=$dir .$extra.$folder.$name."_".$i.$suffix.'.'.$ext[$last];
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$raw=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if(file_exists($nomeFile)){
  unlink($nomeFile);
}
$fp = fopen($nomeFile,'x');
   fwrite($fp, $raw);
   fclose($fp);
   return $name."_".$i.'.'.$ext[$last];
}

}
```

how can I save file only if it's jpg or jpeg files?

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't be looking at the file extension at all.  You should be looking at the `Content-Type` response header for `image/jpeg`.

Comment: to explain **why** you want to check mime-type: if someone uploads a PHP script to your server renamed to `whatever.jpg`, and then you load it as some `<img src="whatever.jpg">` because your code thought it was an image file, guess what your server will do? (hint: yes, it will run that file, with server side permissions, doing anything from deleting all your files to giving someone a backdoor into your server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an if statement:

```
if($ext[$last] == "jpg" || $ext[$last] == "jpeg") {

$fp = fopen($nomeFile,'x');
fwrite($fp, $raw);
fclose($fp);
return $name."_".$i.'.'.$ext[$last];
}
else{
return "";
}
```

Though you should check mime type

```
if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $url);
finfo_close($finfo);
echo $mimetype;
}
```

Comment: instead of "also", it is crazy important to *never* check on extension when user-submitted content is concerned. This lets someone upload an "image" file that's actually a php script, and then the moment it's loaded on the website in an `<img>` element, BAM. Backdoored. Superfun! Super-don't-do-this-ever.